# XMLHTTPRequest XML Parse Error

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data, web-worker

Hi have an the following XML error: "parse and validate the XML file model"

When sending a multipart request.

In Request there is no FormData used because I am doing it inside a Webworker and in IE and FireFox it is not allowed yet.

```
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            boundary = "PostToSNCR__" + Math.random().toString().substr(2),
            xmlBlob = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><files xmlns="http://dv.newbay.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:a="http://alternate.newbay.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:dvi="http://internal.dv.newbay.com/ns/1.0"><file><name>' + smallFile.name + '</name><parentPath>/</parentPath><size>' + smallFile.size + '</size><checksum>' + smallChecksum + '</checksum></file></files>';

            xhr.open('POST', createURL, true);
            headerRequester(xhr);

            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

        var body = '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
            body += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="files"\r\n';
            body += 'Content-Type: application/vnd.newbay.dv-1.0+xml;charset=utf-8\r\n';
            body += 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n';
            body += xmlBlob + '\r\n\r\n';

            body += '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
            body += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' + smallChecksum + '"; filename="' + smallFile.name + '"\r\n';
            body += 'Content-Type: ' + smallFile.type + '\r\n';
            body += 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n';
            body += Uint8.buffer + "\r\n";
            body += '--' + boundary + '--';

            xhr.send(body);
```

How ever if I do it like this outside of a Webworker it works.

```
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            formData = new FormData,
            xmlBlob = ["<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<files xmlns=\"http://dv.newbay.com/ns/1.0\"" +
                                    " xmlns:a=\"http://alternate.newbay.com/ns/1.0\" xmlns:dvi=\"http://internal.dv.newbay.com/ns/1.0\">" +
                                    "\r\n<file>\r\n<name>" + smallFile.name + "</name>\r\n<parentPath>/</parentPath>\r\n<size>" + smallFile.size + "</size>" +
                                    "\r\n<checksum>" + smallChecksum + "</checksum>\r\n</file>\r\n</files>\r\n"],
             bodyBlob = new Blob(xmlBlob, {type : "application/vnd.newbay.dv-1.0+xml;charset=UTF-8"});

             xhr.open('POST', createURL, true);
             headerRequester(xhr);

             formData.append("files", bodyBlob, "files");
             formData.append(checksum, smallFile);

             xhr.send(bodyBlob);
```

How can I resolve so that it works without using FormData and not get the XML error?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a typed array to represent the post body as a js string cannot represent arbitrary binary data.

```
    var body = '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
        body += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="files"\r\n';
        body += 'Content-Type: application/vnd.newbay.dv-1.0+xml;charset=utf-8\r\n';
        body += 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n';
        body += xmlBlob + '\r\n\r\n';

        body += '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
        body += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' + smallChecksum + '"; filename="' + smallFile.name + '"\r\n';
        body += 'Content-Type: ' + smallFile.type + '\r\n';
        body += 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n';
        var end = "\r\n" + '--' + boundary + '--';
        // create a binary post body from the strings and the Uint8 data
        var binbody = new Uint8Array(body.length + Uint8.byteLength + end.length);
        for (var x = 0; nIdx < body.length; x++) {
            binbody[x] = body.charCodeAt(x);
        }
        for (var y = 0; y < Uint8.byteLength; y++) {
            binbody[x+y] = Uint8[y];
        }
        for (var z = 0; z < end.length; z++) {
            binbody[x+y+z] = end.charCodeAt(z);
        }
        xhr.send(binbody);
```